# String manupulation on list of string

Tags: python, string, list

I have this list of string:

```
['2018-10-02 00:00:13,824 INFO  [Pop3SSLServer-1631] [ip=192.168.15.15;oip=190.73.158.8;] security - cmd=Auth; account=kshovelbottomhz_30@ucab.edu.ve; protocol=pop3;\n', '2018-10-02 00:00:15,941 INFO  [Pop3SSLServer-1632] [ip=192.168.15.15;oip=209.85.167.142;] security - cmd=Auth; account=ditzakmz@ucab.edu.ve; protocol=pop3;\n', '2018-10-02 00:00:26,352 INFO  [Pop3SSLServer-1629] [ip=192.168.15.15;oip=209.85.160.166;] security - cmd=Auth; account=bfermerox_21@ucab.edu.ve; protocol=pop3;\n', '2018-10-02 00:00:33,751 INFO  [Pop3SSLServer-1630] [ip=192.168.15.15;oip=209.85.208.131;] security - cmd=Auth; account=bhansenim@ucab.edu.ve; protocol=pop3;\n', '2018-10-02 00:00:57,661 INFO  [Pop3SSLServer-1631] [ip=192.168.15.15;oip=209.85.222.159;] security - cmd=Auth; account=afellibrand67@ucab.edu.ve; protocol=pop3;\n', '2018-10-02 00:01:05,645 INFO  [Pop3SSLServer-1632] [ip=192.168.15.15;oip=209.85.161.37;] security - cmd=Auth; account=sdenys9q@ucab.edu.ve; protocol=pop3;\n', '2018-10-02 00:01:18,683 INFO  [Pop3SSLServer-1633] [ip=192.168.15.15;oip=209.85.167.24;] security - cmd=Auth; account=lpidonqc@ucab.edu.ve; protocol=pop3;']
```

I have this list already obtained in Python. My problem is in how to obtain specific information on each IP. For example 192.168.15.15 or each IP that leaves in the list as for example 90.73.158.8, 209.85.167.142, etc. each protocol that comes out for example pop3. Thank you

Comment: What have you tried?  What specific difficulty are you having?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use re for this task with positive lookahead:

```
import re
In [1]: a = ['2018-10-02 00:00:13,824 INFO [Pop3SSLServer-1631] [ip=192.168.15.15;oip=190.
   ...: 73.158.8;] security - cmd=Auth; account=kshovelbottomhz_30@ucab.edu.ve; protocol=p
   ...: op3;\n', '2018-10-02 00:00:15,941 INFO [Pop3SSLServer-1632] [ip=192.168.15.15;oip=
   ...: 209.85.167.142;] security - cmd=Auth; account=ditzakmz@ucab.edu.ve; protocol=pop3;
   ...: \n', '2018-10-02 00:00:26,352 INFO [Pop3SSLServer-1629] [ip=192.168.15.15;oip=209.
   ...: 85.160.166;] security - cmd=Auth; account=bfermerox_21@ucab.edu.ve; protocol=pop3;
   ...: \n', '2018-10-02 00:00:33,751 INFO [Pop3SSLServer-1630] [ip=192.168.15.15;oip=209.
   ...: 85.208.131;] security - cmd=Auth; account=bhansenim@ucab.edu.ve; protocol=pop3;\n'
   ...: , '2018-10-02 00:00:57,661 INFO [Pop3SSLServer-1631] [ip=192.168.15.15;oip=209.85.
   ...: 222.159;] security - cmd=Auth; account=afellibrand67@ucab.edu.ve; protocol=pop3;\n
   ...: ', '2018-10-02 00:01:05,645 INFO [Pop3SSLServer-1632] [ip=192.168.15.15;oip=209.85
   ...: .161.37;] security - cmd=Auth; account=sdenys9q@ucab.edu.ve; protocol=pop3;\n', '2
   ...: 018-10-02 00:01:18,683 INFO [Pop3SSLServer-1633] [ip=192.168.15.15;oip=209.85.167.
   ...: 24;] security - cmd=Auth; account=lpidonqc@ucab.edu.ve; protocol=pop3;']

In [2]: for i in a:
   ...:     print(re.findall(r'(?<=ip=)([\d\.]+)', i))
   ...:

['192.168.15.15', '190.73.158.8']
['192.168.15.15', '209.85.167.142']
['192.168.15.15', '209.85.160.166']
['192.168.15.15', '209.85.208.131']
['192.168.15.15', '209.85.222.159']
['192.168.15.15', '209.85.161.37']
['192.168.15.15', '209.85.167.24']
```